# How to display specific posts with WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, user-meta, author-template

I need some help with displaying some specific WordPress posts.

User's on my site can click on an 'Add to favorite' link which will then store that post ID in the `user_meta` table for that user as an array.

So when I put the following in my `author.php` template page...

```
<?php 
print_r ($curauth->user_favourite_post) ;
?>
```

... it returns with this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2387
    [1] => 1307
    [2] => 1149
    [3] => 1156
    [4] => 474
    [5] => 50
    [6] => 1131
    [7] => 1473
    [8] => 2388
    [9] => 2544
)
```

... which is all good. This is the post ID's that the user has 'Favorited'.

My question is, how can I display these posts on the author page? I have this...

```
    <?php
$my_query = new WP_Query();
$my_query->query(array( 'post__in' => array($curauth->user_favourite_post)));
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
?>

<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

... But it just displays all of the posts and not the ones that have been 'Favorited' by the user. I've tried a number of different ways and they all just return every post.

Comment: if you copied and paste the code, fix the user favourite _post in the second line, you are using user_favourite_post

Answer (score 2):

Could be because you are passing an array of array try this:

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query();
$my_query->query(array( 'post__in' => $curauth->user_favourite_post));
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
?>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```